# Mobile phone notifications without an app installed?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, mobile, push-notification

Backstory: Like most countries in the world, we've been hit hard with the coronavirus. ***Unlike*** most countries in the world, our country *does not* have an app that tracks the virus. We can go to a government website that gives us an outdated summary, but that's about it.

Issue: we have a popular web-based retail site, and we created a web-based map that tracks coronavirus-confirmed cases. We were also in the process of creating a mobile app that provides info on the virus, but then apple store and google play started blocking apps related to this virus unless it's approved by the government. We've been trying to get approval, but it's an uphill battle.

Since our web-based app tracks all cases in real-time, is it possible to send some type of notification to a mobile phone? For example, a notification would say something like "Another patient has tested positive. Please visit our site for more information".

I've seen services like `Amazon SNS`, but I'm not exactly sure what these services do. I was also considering web push notifications, but I've read that safari doesn't support this. I've also read that `Firebase` can do this, but I'm not sure how.

I guess the question's really a yes/no question: Is it possible to send some type of notification to an iphone or android phone without installing an app? This wouldn't be spam since the user would approve the notifications received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send an SMS message if you know the device's phone number.  You can use FCM on a web app if the user opts into the notification after visiting your site.  Otherwise it's impossible if you don't have an app installed that's designed for receiving and displaying notifications (for good reason).

I suggest researching your options before posting to Stack Overflow - it's for programming questions, not for soliciting ideas for products to solve a problem.

Comment: Btw, FCM on a web app does not work with iphones.